# How can I use Jimp in React Native? If not, is there another compatible package that offers similar functionality?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jimp

I am working on a project where I need to iterate over each pixel or turn the image into a 2D array of dictionaries containing red, green and blue values found in each pixel. I have not yet found a way to do this without Jimp. Is there a version/fork of Jimp that works in React Native? If not, what can I use instead?